# Delete a TestSet in ALM using OTA

Tags: hp-uft, alm

So, I'm SLOWLY working my way to having a painful manual process automated in ALM using OTA.  My current struggle is deleting a test set.  It just doesn't do anything - no error, no deletion, nothing.  It's like the line of code isn't even there.  Although, it's definitely doing something cause ALM is working funky now.

I've tried different things: Delete, RemoveNode. Any advice is appreciated.

```
Set qcConnection = QCutil.QCConnection
Set tsFolder = qcconnection.TestSetTreeManager.NodeById(224)
Set tstestList = tsFolder.FindTestSets("", False, "")

    If tstestList is Nothing Then
        print "No manual tests present", vbOK
    Else

        For i = 1 to tstestList.Count
            Set temp = tstestList.Item(i) 
            if temp.TestSetFolder.father.name = strMonth then
                qcconnection.TSTestFactory.RemoveItem(temp.id)
            end if
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: Maybe `tstestList` is empty?

Comment: @Sergi - I was wondering that, too, so I added a print statement in the inner if loop.  It shows exactly what I want to delete.

Comment: Oh, I see the reason - you use a wrong factory - you need to use `TestSetFactory` instead of `TSTestFactory`

Comment: YES!  You are my hero!!  That worked perfectly.  One of these days, I'll figure out the difference between the factories.  I don't know why I used that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you use a wrong factory - you need to use `TestSetFactory` instead of `TSTestFactory`

Comment: See hero comment above :)